# How can you retrieve the name and version of the application currently running?

Tags: node.js, process

I know one could retrieve the data from the `package.json` when the application is launched from the current node module (i.e. in `node my.js` I can `require('package.json').name`).

But how could I retrieve the information about the current application from a different module? (i.e. an application is launched and it requires a module which requires my module). In that case I need to know what the root application is.

What would be the most efficient and accurate way to retrieve this information?

Comment: I saw some discussions about this. I believe you are looking for a way to get the file descriptor (package.json) from modules, is that right?

Comment: @CelsoAgra not quite (even if this would come handy for another project). What I need is a way to find the module which runs the application originally. I edited my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I don't know if is that solution you are looking for. As I see, you are trying to get some file descriptors about modules.</strike>

Maybe you should get the current file descriptor from any module. I saw some info about `require('module')`, that can be useful for that.

`_resolveLookupPaths` and `_resolveFilename` [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/lib/module.js#L280) are methods that can be useful. but unfortunately, the second method just works for global dependencies. So, Local dependencias are not considered.

I belive this code can help you to get the full path of a module:

```
// my own file descriptor
var packageJson = require('./package.json');
console.log(packageJson);

// module file descriptor
var moduleName = 'mongoose'; // change module name
var modulePath = require('module')._resolveLookupPaths('./');
var moduleDescriptor = require(modulePath[1][1] + '/' + moduleName + '/package.json');
console.log(moduleDescriptor.version);
```

when you run this method:

```
var modulePath = require('module')._resolveLookupPaths('./');
```

the output is always the same:

```
[ './',
  [ '.',
    '/home/<username>/<folder>/<sub-folder>/node_modules',
    '/home/<username>/<folder>/node_modules',
    '/home/<username>/node_modules',
    ... ] ]
```

So the full path for me is `modulePath[1][1]`
I believe with that you can create the real path of any local module. But I really don't know if this is the best or official way to get a file descriptor info of any module.

**edit:**

Maybe this can help you:

```
// index.js
require('mymodule').init();
```

In node modules:

```
// node_modules/mymodule/index.js
module.exports.init = function() {
    var pack = require(process.cwd() + '\\package.json'); // I'm running on windows!!
    console.log(pack.version); // output 1.0.0
}
```

the output is (according to app that is calling my module):

```
// 1.0.0
```

Comment: The main problem I have is that I don't know which module I am looking for. My module which can be used by any other module needs to find what application is using it.

Comment: maybe the method `process.cwd()` can be useful for you